# Correct syntax for adding a key=>value pair to existing object in puppet?

Tags: puppet

I'm hacking away at the `puppetlabs-haproxy` module (https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-haproxy) and I'm trying to add the ability to detect whether a particular haproxy listener should have a stats listener enabled. Here's what I've got:

```
define haproxy::listen (
  $ports,
  $ipaddress        = $::ipaddress,
  $mode             = 'tcp',
  $collect_exported = true,
  $stats_uri        = false,
  $options          = {
    'option'  => [
      'tcplog',
    ],
    'balance' => 'roundrobin',
  }
) {
  if ($stats_uri) {
    $options['stats'] => 'uri /' #<=======SYNTAX ERROR HERE
  }
  # Template uses: $name, $ipaddress, $ports, $options
  concat::fragment { "${name}_listen_block":
    order   => "20-${name}-1",
    target  => '/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg',
    content => template('haproxy/haproxy_listen_block.erb'),
  }

  if $collect_exported {
    Haproxy::Balancermember <<| listening_service == $name |>>
  }
  # else: the resources have been created and they introduced their
  # concat fragments. We don't have to do anything about them.
}
```

The main difference is that I've added a parameter `$stats_uri`, and I'm trying to test whether that's set and add a key/value pair into `$options` if it is.

Currently, I'm getting a syntax error, because you obviously don't do this like I'm doing in the marked line.

So the question is, how do I maipulate the `$options` object based on whether `$stats_uri` is set or not?

Answer (score 1):

Well, `$options['stats'] = 'uri /'` probably works.  But don't do it that way - [depending on an unintended behavior isn't a good idea](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/16116).

Instead, make the different options their own parameters:

```
define haproxy::listen (
  $ports,
  $ipaddress        = $::ipaddress,
  $mode             = 'tcp',
  $collect_exported = true,
  $stats_uri        = false,
  $option           = [ 'tcplog' ],
  $option_balance   = 'roundrobin',
  $option_stats     = undef,
) {
  if ($stats_uri) {
    $options_stats = 'uri /'
  }
```

Comment: Typically, I'd agree this is the right way to go. However, this particular module uses `concat` with a template, and it literally just loops through the `$options` array and splurges out the key => value parings into the output file (see https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-haproxy/blob/master/templates/haproxy_listen_block.erb). Hence wanting to dynamically add something into `$options` so I can just output it. Is the right answer here 'Change the template and do it properly'?

Comment: @growse That's what I'd probably go for.  But another option might be the `merge` function in puppet-stdlib - see [here](http://puppetlabs.com/blog/module-of-the-week-puppetlabs-stdlib-puppet-labs-standard-library-part-4/).

Comment: @ShaneMadden was moved [here](https://puppet.com/blog/module-of-week-puppetlabs-stdlib-puppet-labs-standard-library-part-4).